# How to implement hasOne with optional relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, orm

I have a customer table like this

```
id
name
```

Another table policy like this

```
id
policy_name
```

and yet another table policy_customer like this

```
id 
customer_id
policy_id
```

In my customer model I have written like this

```
    protected $appends = ['policy_customer'];

    public function policy_customer() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\PolicyCustomer', "customer_id", "id");
    }

    public function getPolicyCustomerAttribute(){
        return $this->policy_customer()->firstOrFail();
    }
```

and in PolicyCustomer model

```
    public function policy() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Policy', "policy_id", "id");
    }

    public function customer() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Customer', "customer_id", "id");
    }
```

All customers may not have a policy associated with their account. 
When I query for Customer::get() there is no issue. But if I try to return this as the response of the controller, I am getting an error like the below:

```
[2020-02-06 06:11:47] local.ERROR: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException: No query results for model [App\Models\PolicyCustomer]. in D:\Projects\others\jayhawker\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder.php:454
Stack trace:
#0 D:\Projects\others\jayhawker\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Traits\ForwardsCalls.php(23): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->firstOrFail()
#1 D:\Projects\others\jayhawker\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation.php(385): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation->forwardCallTo(Object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder), 'firstOrFail', Array)
#2 D:\Projects\others\jayhawker\backend\app\Models\Customer.php(41): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation->__call('firstOrFail', Array)
#3 D:\Projects\others\jayhawker\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasAttributes.php(454): App\Models\Customer->getPolicyAttribute(NULL)
#
```

If I remove the getPolicyCustomerAttribute function from Customer model, it is not throwing the exception.
Am I missing something?

Comment: ur database look like `many-to-many`.

Comment: what's the relationship between policy and customer?

Comment: you can use `many-to-many` relationships.

Comment: I tried many to many also. it still throws the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove your `getPolicyCustomerAttribute` accessor method. All relationship methods automatically provide an attribute of the same name that will contain the results of the relationship.

That is, `$customer->policy_customer` will either contain the related PolicyCustomer instance, or it will be `null` if there is no related record.

```
$customer->policy_customer === $customer->policy_customer()->first();
```

Comment: If I remove getPolicyCustomerAttribute the error will be gone, but the object is not in the resultant json